# LTspice repeating arb voltage (BV) block

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I am trying to generate a rectified sinewave with a "flat" DC top. I managed to generate 1 cycle (shown).

I used an arb voltage (BV) block, now I just need to get this to repeat, for x cycles.

Below is the Value in the BV block

```
V= DC*sin(pi*time/cycle_period)*(time < cycle_period/2) + DC*(time >= cycle_period/2)*(time < cycle_period) + DC * sin(pi*(time - (cycle_period/2))/(cycle_period))*(time >= cycle_period)*(time < 3*cycle_period/2)
```

[image]

I feel like this is the correct approach, but I cannot find a way to make this periodic.

Comment: Aside from creating something with that general shape,  a differentiable function is usually preferable for convergence reasons. Because of time constraints, I'm not going to give an answer here, but a hint is to involve tanh() for soft clipping.

Answer (score 2):

I will not re-create your function but I'll try a simpler way.

As you know, you can use `func` operator to define user-defined functions.

With this, you can define two functions:

- One for regular rectified sine:

`.func Fs(time) { DC * 1.5 * abs(sin * 2 * pi * time / cycle_period) }`

- The other for clipping:

`.func Fx(time) { (Fs(time) < DC) * FS(time) + (Fs(time) >= DC) * DC }`

And put `V = Fx(time)` in your bv's Value field.

---

Note that the peak in the first function, `DC * 1.5`, is an arbitrarily defined peak to demonstrate the clipped top, so can be anything higher than `DC`. Also the result has "hard-clipped" peaks rather than the soft-clipped ones as shown in your waveform.

Here's the result I had:

[image]

PS: You defined a cycle period of 0.1 seconds, `cycle_period`, but the result has 150 ms as can be seen in your plot. Because you plot the sine for the first 50 milliseconds, then plot a clipped top for 50 milliseconds, and finally plot the remaining sine for another 50 milliseconds.

Comment: Hi Rohat, I see what you did. This will do fine.

Comment: Regarding your cycle period comment, yes this is something I will fix, was just trying to get the basic right to begin with..... Many thanks